# Unir campos de tabla con diferente ID

Tags: php, mysql, join

Tengo esta tabla en MySQL:

```
    +-------------------------------+
    | *UDH*        |     *Text*     |
    --------------------------------
    | 050003B90301 | Hola soy A     |
    --------------------------------
    | 050003B90302 | rmin y quier   |
    --------------------------------
    | 050003B90303 | o ser amigo tuy|
    --------------------------------
    | 050003310201 | Me llamo Ana y |
    --------------------------------
    | 050003310202 | soy modelo prof|
    +-------------------------------+
```

Como pueden ver, los datos de la columna UDH son iguales a diferencia del último caracter, y necesito unir el campo **Text** en uno solo, algo así:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
| *UDH* |     *Text*                            |
-------------------------------------------------
| 1     | Hola soy Armin y quiero ser amigo tuy |
-------------------------------------------------
| 2     | Me llamo Ana y soy modelo prof        |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

He tratado con la sentencia: *group_concat()* de MySQL pero no lo he conseguido... Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: cual es la condición para juntar textos? que el primer carácter de "text" este en mayúsculas?

Comment: El campo UDH lleva una numeración en el último caractér los primeros 11 son iguales...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con group concat funciona te dejo el codigo y un ejemplo online

`SELECT 
substr(UDH,1,11) as id,
GROUP_CONCAT( Text SEPARATOR  '' ) as texto
FROM test
group by substr(UDH,1,11)`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee99d/14

Comment: para diferentes id

Comment: el ejemplo esta con distintos id

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona de maravillas, pero ahora se me ha olvidado especificar que en la columna UDH hay campos vacíos, por lo tanto esos no se deben unir, alguna otra sentencia que añadir a la consulta?

Comment: seria algo asi SELECT 
substr(UDH,1,11) as id,
GROUP_CONCAT( Text SEPARATOR  '' ) as texto
FROM test
where UDH!=''
group by substr(UDH,1,11)

Comment: Tambien funciona, pero hay tuplas en los que UDH está vacío, por lo tanto no hay necesidad de concatenar el texto del campo Text...

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a utilizar un Inner Join.
Te dejo un link muy interesante. Pero intento explicartelo:

http://www.blogdephp.com/consulta-mysql-inner-join-para-unir-tablas-relacionadas/

```
// Consulta Mysql donde aplicamos INNER JOIN

$consulta_mysql="select NombreDelatabla1.Text,NombredeTabla2.Text
                 from NombreDelatabla1
                 inner join NombreDelaTabla2 
                 on NombreDelatabla1.UDH=NombreDelatabla2.UDH"; 
                 // <-- Aqui hacemos el inner join con la ID
```

Answer (score 0):

te estaban faltando 2 cosas:

1.- Un `GROUP BY` para el `query` usando solo los caracteres que necesitas.

2.- Lo mas practico en tu caso es usar `group_concat` definiendo un separador vacío.

Primero, dejame aclarar que la mejor solución seria tener en una columna el ID único y en otra un numero incremental ya que podrías crear indices y optimizar los `queries` pero como desconozco que tanto registros tenga tu base de datos y si va a tener o no un uso intensivo solo te acerco la solución a tu problema.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(text SEPARATOR '')
AS message FROM `test_table` GROUP BY SUBSTR(udh,1,10) order by udh DESC
```

En este ejemplo, solo debería reemplazar test_table por el nombre de tu tabla y verificar los nombres de los campos por que en mi ejemplo los detallo en minúsculas.

para solo utilizar los primeros 10 caracteres de UDH la funcion que utilizo para agrupar es SUBSTR